# Каков принцип работы очередей в laravel?

Tags: laravel

Каков принцип работы очередей в laravel?

Например, если мне нужно, чтобы письма отправлялись не сразу, а стекались в некую очередь и потом исполнялись, например, раз в полчаса.
Если можно, то с примером.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Фрагмент документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#queueing-mail), перевод и оригинал (на случай неточностей перевода):

**Очередь отправки почтовых сообщений**

> **Queueing A Mail Message**

Поскольку отправка сообщений электронной почты может существенно увеличить время отклика приложения, многие разработчики принимают решение о реализации очереди для фоновой отправки сообщений. Laravel облегчает эту задачу посредством встроенного унифицированного API очередей. Чтобы поставить отправку сообщения в очередь, используйте метод `queue` на фасаде (речь о паттерне?) `Mail`:

> Since sending e-mail messages can drastically lengthen the response time of your application, many developers choose to queue e-mail messages for background sending. Laravel makes this easy using its built-in unified queue API. To queue a mail message, use the queue method on the Mail facade:

```
Mail::queue('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    //
});
```

Этот метод автоматически помещает задачу в очередь, позволяя отправить сообщение в фоновом режиме. Разумеется, чтобы использовать эту возможность, вам придется сначала сконфигурировать очереди.

> This method will automatically take care of pushing a job onto the queue to send the mail message in the background. Of course, you will need to configure your queues before using this feature.

**Отложенная очередь сообщений**

> **Delayed Message Queueing**

Если вы хотите отложить отправку поставленного в очередь сообщения, можете использовать нижеприведенный метод. В качестве первого аргумента метода передайте необходимое количество секунд задержки.

> If you wish to delay the delivery of a queued e-mail message, you may use the later method. To get started, simply pass the number of seconds by which you wish to delay the sending of the message as the first argument to the method:

```
Mail::later(5, 'emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
     //
});
```

**Отправка в конкретную очередь**

> **Pushing To Specific Queues**

Если хотите указать конкретную очередь, в которую должно уйти сообщение, используйте методы `queueOn` и `laterOn`:

> If you wish to specify a specific queue on which to push the message, you may do so using the queueOn and laterOn methods:

```
Mail::queueOn('queue-name', 'emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    //
});

Mail::laterOn('queue-name', 5, 'emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
   //
});
```

Comment: Так, а инициировать исполнение очереди не требуется, то есть она исполняется автоматически никаких задач по крону не надо исполнять?

Comment: Собственно почему интересует этот вопрос, в случае если требуется отправка рассылки в какое то время определенное например в ночное, то как это реализовывается с помощью очередей или это реализуется с помощью команды?

Comment: "Разумеется, чтобы использовать эту возможность, вам придется сначала сконфигурировать очереди" как ее сконфигурировать?

Comment: http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues#14-about-queues здесь примеры как запускать с кроном/без крона, цитировать не буду так как много текста. Про конфигурацию почитайте здесь https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#configuration